# Summarize and multiplication between tables

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I work in a lightrail-company, and I am responsible for the passenger counting. 
We have automatic passenger counting on one tram, but we have 16 trams at the most in traffic. 
I am looking for a way to multiply sum of boarded passengers and number of trams in traffic.

I have a MYSQL database, "Telledata".

I have two tables, "tram_usage_fri", this is a table who shows how many trams that are in use at any given time of the day.

[image: tram_usage_fri screenshot]

and "Vogn217", which has all the information about passenger counting.

[image: Vogn217 screenshot].

Lets take an example: 
Table tram_usage_fri: Between 14:10 and 17:41 we have 16 trams in traffic. 
Table Vogn 217: I want to summarize number of passengers between 14:10 and 17:41 and multiply this by 16 trams from table "tram_usage_fri".

Is this even possible?

Comment: That will definitelly not be possible in Tableau and with a quick look on your data it will probably be difficult with other tools as well since there can be multiple records for a certain time period.

Comment: Hello again! I ended up with doing it all in a query, like this: SELECT Date, Time, Station, Boarded, Departed, Last,
CASE 
WHEN Time > "04:00:00" && Time < "04:47:00" && WEEKDAY(Date) <= 3 THEN Boarded * 1
WHEN Time > "04:47:00" && Time < "05:10:00" && WEEKDAY(Date) <= 3 THEN Boarded * 2
WHEN Time > "05:10:00" && Time < "05:25:00" && WEEKDAY(Date) <= 3 THEN Boarded * 3
WHEN Time > "05:25:00" && Time < "05:28:00" && WEEKDAY(Date) <= 3 THEN Boarded * 4
And so on :)

Comment: That seems like an overly complicated and not very flexible or maintanable solution. But if that works for you I guess it's good for now...