# Generating values in cells based on other cells in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I work with passenger counting in a rail-company, and I have a question. 
We only have automatic passenger counting system in on train, and that train doesnt go every hour of the day.

**Here** you see a table of when I have data, and when I dont have data:

[image: Here you see a table of when I have data, and when I dont have data.]

I want to generate/calculate numbers in the white fields, based on the other fields, so we can have more correct total numbers of passengers.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. The Tableau feature that best fits this problem goes by the name of "table calculations" or "table calcs" for short. Start simple and learn about how table calcs work in general, then apply to your specific problem.

Comment: I would say it depends a bit on what kind of calculation you want to do. Can you give more details?

Comment: @Alexander - I suspect it's related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916408/summarize-and-multiplication-between-tables

Comment: @Talvalin jep saw that question as well. But either it is a duplicate or it needs a lot more information because just by the current question the answer can only be "Maybe"

Comment: Hello again, sorry for the late reply. Let us say that between 6AM and 7AM on a monday, we know there is approx. 300 passengers travelling. Then if we dont have data, we want the number in the "white field" to be 300. This is so we can have a reliable Grand total summary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Pad data using `IFNULL` inbuilt Function.

```
IFNULL(SUM([NUMBER_OF_PASSENGER]),WINDOW_AVG(SUM([NUMBER_OF_PASSENGER])))
```

Instead of `WINDOW_AVG` you might select any other Analytics you want like `WINDOW_SUM` , `WINDOW_MAX` etc, whatever fits best .

Remember this is table calculation so your original measure must be there in the Sheet, you can hide it later in the viz .

Let me know if this works for you.